# JSF + PrimeFaces - Erro HTTP 404

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Bom dia,

Web não é minha praia mais estou querendo aprender.
Criei o projeto como "Dynamic Web" depois convertir para Maven porque estava dando uns erros e jeito que parou de dá erro foi o descrito acima.

Não fiz nenhuma configuração além de definiri *.xhtml no web.xml.

Estou colocando algumas imagens para que possa ajuda em algo e inclusive as informações do console.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente adicionar essas bibliotecas em seu pom.xml:

```
<!-- API de Servlet -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- Implementação do JSF -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.8</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Certifique-se de que seu `pom.xml` contém a dependência para a API do [JSF](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.faces/jsf-api/2.1), no erro mostra que não consegue encontrar a classe dessa API.

Para toda especificação do Java EE que estiver utilizando também precisa de uma implementação.

> Com exemplo em suas escolhas da tela de Facets

- Para a especificação de JSF, existe as implementações [Mojarra](https://javaserverfaces.java.net/),
  [MyFaces](https://myfaces.apache.org/), [RichFaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/) e [Primefaces](http://www.primefaces.org/).
- Para [JPA](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.javax.persistence/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api) existe as implementações [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/), [Eclipse Link](https://eclipse.org/eclipselink/) e
  [OpenJPA](https://openjpa.apache.org/)

Escolha uma das implementações e adicione nas dependencias em seu pom.xml, seguido da API de sua especificação.

Existem dois sites que pode usar para pegar as dependencias para o maven.

```
http://mvnrepository.com/
https://search.maven.org/
```

Exemplos:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.richfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>richfaces-core-impl</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.7.Final</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: No meu caso só o primefaces mesmo, como ficaria? usando o "javax.faces?"

Comment: Da uma olhada em um dos dois sites que mencionei, digite Primefaces, escolha a versão e adicione. Utilize o jsf-api junto ao primefaces, sua implementação. Mas deixo aqui para entender melhor http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.3

Answer (score 0):

**Solução...**

```
<dependency>
```

com.sun.faces
  jsf-api
  2.1.13


  com.sun.faces
  jsf-impl
  2.1.13


  javax.servlet
  javax.servlet-api
  3.0.1